# Compare postgresql execution plan

Tags: database-partitioning, postgresql-12

I'm trying to determine the best size for partitioning my biggest tables on Postgresql 12.

So far, I've tried 3 scenarios and executed an explain analyze on my slowest queries that are impacted by these tables after each partitioning.

Now that I'm looking at the data I gathered, I'm asking my self if choosing just the execution time is the right criteria to determine the best scenario.

Is there another (better) parameter I should be considering ?

Comment: Partitioning isn't primarily a performance tuning tool. But if used with that intention, it will only help if all of your queries (or at least those for which the performance matters) include the partitioning key in the WHERE clause - ideally limiting the result to rows from exactly one partition. How many rows does your table contain?

Comment: The queries I run my tests on include the partitioning key in the WHERE clause. And to answer your second question my biggest table have around 321 M rows (and yes it is still not partitioned)